# How can I allow moderated anonymous contributors to post to my blog?

Tags: plugins, moderation

How can I allow moderated anonymous contributors to post to my blog?

Comment: how are you moderating anonymous users in the first place? do you just want anonymous people to be able to contribute posts, and then approve them manually?

Comment: Right, I want to be able to let anonymous people contribute posts, and have these show up as posts I can publish / delete / edit, etc. Also, if you have questions use the "add comment" feature.

Comment: Look into the gravity forms.. perhaps the posts can be in "draft" stage? Secondly, use the email interface, and make sure all posts are drafts by default.. then you can mark the ones you want as "published"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably either use [GravityForms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) or [CForms](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/) plugins to allow that, both have a "form to post" feature that creates a new post and lets the admin moderate it before publishing.

Comment: Just a small correction to my answer, it's TDO mini forms like Adam said and not CForms.
My experience is mostly with GravityForms though that's worth every cent.